# Jenkins Node without Java

Tags: java, jenkins

Is it possible to register a *nix machine as a Jenkins slave node *without* having Java installed on the slave machine? In another words, does there exist any alternatives for communication between the master and node to `slave.jar`?

A [thread](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Java-less-slave-td383073.html) from some years ago hints that it is not possible. I am wondering if it has changed since then.

Answer (score -2):

Try the "Java Web Start" method (configured when configuring the slave). It will use the Java from the web-browser that starts it.

Obviously, this is a manual start and requires a UI (Ubuntu?)

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I am aware this method still requires java on the client machine.